# Check mark button controlling map

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, jsfiddle

Ok, I asked a similar question yesterday - but I need help again because I rearranged my code.

SEE HERE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/10/

As you can see- there is a map and a checkmark box. I want the check mark box to control the color of the countries.

For example: when checked (checked on load) I want it to highlight certain countries on the map. And when unchecked to display them in a different color.

```
        new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        container: $('#mymap'),
        backgroundColor: '#314F73',
        zoomMax: 40,
        markers: markers,
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#ffffff'
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                scale: {
                    '1': '#B1C9C0',
                        '2': '#41a62a'
                },
                attribute: 'fill',
                values: data1['countriesvisited']
            }]
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').fancyfields();
    var mapObject = $('#mymap').jvm.WorldMap('get', 'mapObject');
    $("#Checkbox1").fancyfields("bind", "onCheckboxChange", function (input, isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            console.log(mapObject.series.regions[0]);
            mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale({
                '1': '#ffffff',
                    '2': '#000000'
            });
        } else {
            mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale({
                '1': '#000000',
                    '2': '#ffffff'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So using the above code:

On load it would load WITH all the:
'1' parameter countries with COLOR #B1C9C0
'2' parameter countries with COLOR #41A62A

on checkmark: 
'1' parameter countries with COLOR #ffffff
'2' parameter countries with COLOR #000000

on uncheck:
'1' parameter countries with COLOR #000000
'2' parameter countries with COLOR #ffffff

Well that's what I want it to do. I am not sure I am getting the info from the map correctly though.

please help !

Comment: `$('#mymap').jvm` is undefined in your jsFiddle

Comment: What should I be referencing then to get the mapobjects?